# MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 2001

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Release/Debug ARM deploy to device isn't possible. But the build succeeds.

I get following exception:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error      Error : DEP6810 :
>   MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 2001. See log file
>   'C:\Users..\obj\ARM\Debug\MDIL\MDILXapCompileLog.txt' for more
>   details.

MDILXapCompileLog.txt:

> CrossGen failed Error processing assembly
>   C:\Users...\obj\ARM\Debug\MSIL\Microsoft.Band.dll Raw error code:
>   2148733978

Google lead me to following solution:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Navigate to YourSolution/Packages/
3. Delete everything except packages.config
4. Reopen the solution in Visual Studio
5. Right click on solution and select "Manage Nuget Packages"
6. Click the "Restore" button that appears at the top of the dialog
   window

Doesn't work for me. Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't add a comment <em>due to my low reputation of my profile</em> :(, anyway I write this note hoping it could be useful (and to make this page as a result for Google for my specific error).
The answer marked as solution works for me as well (unistall and reinstall the app) even if my error was this: CrossGen failed<br/> Raw error code: 2148733978 Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If WP 8.1, uninstall the app and run deploy, it worked for me.

Comment: Worked on Windows 10 Mobile as well.

Comment: This was driving me crazy, thnx pal

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy the Device make sure to select Debug instead of Release. If you set to Release the app will not be deployed and the above error will occur.
Select Debug and set the deployment destination as Device. Unlock the phone and run. It will work.